# How to change style property on button onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an element in react that I want to hide when I click a button.

The element styles are loaded at the constructor like this:

```
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  display: 'block'
};
this.ElementStyle= {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
  color: '#404040',
  padding: '8px 15px',
  boxSizing: 'content-box',
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: '0',
  display: this.state.display
    }
  }
```

And the element has got a button inside it's render() calling a function that changes state like so:

```
render()  {
  <button onClick={this.Method.bind(this)}>Click me </button>
}
```

And the Method():

```
  Method() {
    this.setState({
      display: 'none'
    });
  }
```

And then I have this:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    this.ElementStyle.display = this.state.display;
  }
```

This however is saying: `"TypeError: "display" is read-only"`

Comment: In my current project, I utilized jquery in the componentDidMount() method to accomplish this. I've seen recommendation against this, however, so I too would like to see thoughts on this.

Comment: If you use jquery in react (if you are not wrapping a non-react library) may be you are using it in the wrong way. There are multiple approach to this task, and the simpliest is to define two classes in you CSS and switch className (without relying on jQuery)

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini well I didn't import jquery simply for the toggle method that's for sure. But I get what you're saying, I've utilized vanilla js and css for this task as well. My point really is just that including all these different things in the component state gets tedious. My perception of state was that it is meant to keep track of user input data. When you start getting into storing basic UI functionality in state, just seems overkill I guess. I'll have to get used to this notion as it's apparently the 'correct' way.

Comment: It dependes, I usually store the UI state in Redux along with datas as when a bug is detected BugSnag send the complete history of states to my debugger and I can reproduce both data and UI state when error occurred. It is sure that is better to manage the single css in CSS/Styled-components/SASS/LESS or similar and take in consideration to work simply with classes

Answer (score 4):

Simply Place your styles in state:

### State

```
this.state = {
  ElementStyle: {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
  color: '#404040',
  padding: '8px 15px',
  boxSizing: 'content-box',
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: '0',
  display: 'block
};
```

### Method

```
 Method() {
    this.setState({
      ElementStyle: {
      ...this.state.ElementStyle,
      display: 'none'
      }
    });
  }
```

### Render

```
render()  {
  <button style={this.state.ElementStyle} onClick={this.Method.bind(this)}>Click me </button>
}
```

Comment: This is a question I've often had. What should be included in state? I started to do this, and my state object started getting VERY cluttered in one of my components. Is this considered good practice?

Comment: Manipulating CSS from state is bad idea. `display` property would always render the element no matter the state is. So, good practice is not to render element at all is the state is false.

Comment: @silencedogood maybe you need to refactor that one component. Ex: <my-button />

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar you are right but not for the right reason. Manipulate styles in state is bad for separation of concerns, imagine to add the whole css management in every component for every element..this is why I use styled-components/css modules/plain css.
Another additional way is to make the css to be returned by a method that checks the state. But really, the old fashioned "two CSS class approach" for this task is the best fit.

Comment: @wakajawaka yeah perhaps. I had lazy loader state in there, css, all kinds of stuff. Finally I went with jquery to whittle things down. Refactoring would certainly be the best answer I suppose. So much modularization can get annoying though, in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

no did wrong
react has a virtual dom, and it's managed automatically, but you are trying to change its behavior,
I think you can do it like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       display: 'block'
    };
}


Method() {
   this.setState({
       display: 'none'
   });
}


render()  {
  <div>
     <div style={{display: this.state.display}} ></div>
     <button onClick={this.Method.bind(this)}>Click me </button>
  </div>
}
```

you also have several options too, but it is simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is style your component and set the display initialy to none, 
like:

```
// css
.yoourclass {
 width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
  color: '#404040',
  padding: '8px 15px',
  boxSizing: 'content-box',
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: '0',
  display: none
    }

}

//have a class that show display to block
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Then in your javascript

```
// set your state to some display property 
this.state = {
   showHiddenElement: false
}

//then you can set state to display css like
const {showHiddenElement} = this.state;
this.setState({
  showHiddenElement: !showHiddenElement
})
// and in your component 
// apply the class bases on the state like
const toggle = this.state.showHiddenElement;
<yourelement className={`yoourclass ${toggle? 'show' : ''}`}
```

Something like that, I hope this makes sense, let me know. It is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you're trying to set style using `style` property, but how we usually do this is using css classes and css stylesheets. And in runtime we modify classes instead of element styles.

So, for your case, we would have that style as some class like in, let's say `App.scss`

```js
.class-to-be-applied {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    color: #404040;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

    .no-display {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

and in `App.js`,

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import './App.scss';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: true
        };
    }
    handleButtonClick = () => {
        this.setState(({ display }) => ({display: !display}));
    }
    render()  {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click me </button>
                <SomeComponent className={classnames('class-to-be-applied', {'no-display': !this.state.display})} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Other way to do the same thing and more preferred way is to just not render it at all to avoid inserted into the tree itself, like below for `App.js`,

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import './App.scss';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: true
        };
    }
    handleButtonClick = () => {
        this.setState(({ display }) => ({display: !display}));
    }

    render()  {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click me </button>
                { this.state.display && <SomeComponent className=class-to-be-applied' /> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Put your object inside inline CSS :-

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ this.Method.bind(this) }>Click me </button>
            <h1 style={{
                 width: '100%',
                 backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
                 color: '#404040',
                 padding: '8px 15px',
                 boxSizing: 'content-box',
                 position: 'fixed',
                 bottom: '0',
                 display:this.state.display
            }}>About</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

2) And remove this **shouldComponentUpdate()** function

```
 shouldComponentUpdate() {
this.ElementStyle.display = this.state.display;
}
```